# Javascript click event with nested element

Tags: javascript, events, click

i want to ask how to select the `element` properly.
When i click on the icon it gives me the `i` tag element but is nested inside an `anchor` tag. Which approach is correct:

```
// First Approach
if(e.target.parentElement.dataset.role === 'edit') {
 // Do something
}

// Second Approach
if(e.target.dataset.role === 'edit') {
 // Do something
}

<li>
 <a href="#" class="secondary-content" data-role="edit"> <!-- Parent element -->
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <!-- nested edit icon -->
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `target` property of the event object will be the element that was clicked on.

Use `currentTarget` to get the element to which the event handler was bound.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.role);
}
```

```css
span {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button data-role="edit">
      Click Me
      <span>Click Me</span>
     </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add a unique id to your i element, 
`<i  id=“some-id ” class=“fa fa-pencil”>`
and could do something like:

`document.querySelector(‘#some-id’)`

Or

`document.getElementById(‘some-id’)`

Or

`document.querySelector(‘a i.fa-pencil’)` or something like that.